# extract parameter value from string through vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

I want to read (V) parameter value for this string using vb.net

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzPUXXXXXX

I want to read after "v=", how to perform this using vb.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in VB.Net it would be:

```
' this takes request parameters only from the query string
Request.QueryString("v")

' this one works for both - form and query string
Request("v")
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using the below code

```
        Dim V As String = Split(txtlink.text, "=")(1)


        Dim tube As New StringBuilder
        tube.Append("<iframe width=""500"" height=""500"" src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/" & V & """ frameborder=0></iframe>")
```